# How do I detect if ActiveX is enabled in the browser of client?

Tags: javascript, activex

How do I detect if ActiveX is enabled in the browser of client?

I tried following code, but it's not working in Firefox.

```
window.ActiveXObject not working in Firefox
```

any ideas?

check the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qXSvQ/2/

I get `false` when I run this example.

Answer (score 26):

ActiveX objects do not exist in anything but Internet Explorer. If you're trying to use them for XMLHTTPRequests, use the XMLHTTPRequest() object instead, using feature detection.

```
if ("ActiveXObject" in window) { /* Do ActiveX Stuff */ }
else { /* ActiveX doesnt exist, use something else */ }
```

Comment: This works fine in IE11 and Chrome, unlike window.ActiveXObject (which always returns "undefined")

Answer (score 9):

What isn't working?  Is that throwing an error in FF?  How about

```
var hasAX = "ActiveXObject" in window;
```

Comment: no, I get false in firefox and chrome from this. see  http://jsfiddle.net/qXSvQ/2/

Comment: @twesh It **should** return false in Firefox and Chrome; neither FireFox nor Chrome support ActiveX. You are running code to determine if FireFox or Chrome support ActiveX. Since neither FireFox or Chrome support ActiveX, the function should return `false`. Testing the actual code in FireFox and Chrome, it correctly returns `false`. Is there something missing from the answer?

Answer (score 8):

Below code should work, It is working on IE6 & FF 3.6.12 atleast.

```
if(typeof(window.ActiveXObject)=="undefined"){
    alert("ActiveX Object not supported");
}else {
    alert("ActiveX Object  supported");
}
```

Comment: its working fine in `IE`, but in firefox it is undefined. I have checked with `FF 3.6.12` and `FF 4.0b7`.

Comment: @twesh, undefined is fine that is ActiveX is not supported in FF. Even in above code also, I've compared it with "undefined" only.

Comment: so any workarounds to check if ActiveX is enabled in the FF browser?

Comment: @twesh - Firefox **never** supports ActiveX.  As Chinmayee said, Firefox will always return `undefined`.  Perhaps you mean something other than ActiveX, if you expect FF to support it?

Comment: actually I need to check if ActiveX is enabled or not for tracking purpose. how does google analytics detect ActiveX?

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle He might be thinking of the binary plug-in system used by Chrome/Netscape/Firefox. All browsers have a binary plug-in system. In Internet Explorer, they are painless to install and called ActiveX. In other browsers they are called [*NPAPI plugins*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI). Knowing if the user agent supports NPAPI would be useful for then showing the user a download link (e.g. maps.google.com and the Google Earth NPAPI plugin). But, in the end, the question was about **ActiveX**, not **NPAPI**, so this is the right answer.

Comment: According to this IE with the activex settings on doesn't supports activex, even when I can see the `window.ActiveXObject` property in the `window` element, I'd stick with @MPD answer, which shows the correct value

Comment: Weird, doesn't seem to work in IE11. It says that window.ActiveXObject is undefined, yet I can still create a new ActiveXObject by writing 'var something = new ActiveXObject("PCDClient.PCDLogin.1");' in the console

Comment: This answer is not correct on IE11, where it will sometimes create false-negatives. See this screenshot, where ActiveX is clearly available, but `typeof(window.ActiveXObject)' is `undefined`. Philip Pryce's answer below works correctly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNknO.png

Answer (score 1):

It seems Firefox simply skips scripts containing ActiveX objects:

```
<script><!--
  var activeXsupport = "ActiveX not supported";
// --></script>

<script><!--
  var dummy = new ActiveXObject ('WScript.Shell');
  activeXsupport = "ActiveX supported";
// --></script>

<script><!--
  alert (activeXsupport);
// --></script>
```

So this gives me "supported" on IE11 and "not supported" on Firefox.

[Edit:] Since it also throws an error message on Firefox if the console is opened with [F12], I suggest this improvement:

```
<script><!--   
  var dummy = ''; var hasActiveX = false;  
  try {dummy = new ActiveXObject ('WScript.Shell'); hasActiveX = true;}
  catch (err) {dummy = ''; hasActiveX = false;}
  alert ('hasActiveX = ' + hasActiveX);
// --></script>
```

Edge Chromium supports ActiveX if it is made the default browser in settings and reloading in Internet Explorer Mode via "More Tools" is enabled:

```
edge://settings/defaultBrowser
```

Gerolf