# JavaScript Scheduler implementation using promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I was solving this interesting javascript problem (interview question) and I got stuck on how I can implement this using promises.

**Problem:**

> Write a scheduler in JavaScript that accepts max number of concurrent
>   tasks as a parameter and schedules tasks (each task may take arbitrary
>   time to complete).

Please note that we need to only execute "n" (concurrent) tasks at a time before proceeding to execute other tasks.

This is my implementation:

```js
var exampleTaskA = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Task A Done');
    }, 1000);
};

function TaskRunner(concurrency) {
    this.limit = concurrency;
    this.store = [];
    this.len = this.store.length;
}

TaskRunner.prototype.push = function (task) {
    this.store.push(task);
    function getWorker(store, limit) {
        if(!store.length) return;

        if(store.length <= limit) {
            const cur = store.shift();
            if(cur) cur();
            getWorker(store, limit);
        }
    }

    getWorker(this.store, this.limit);
}

var task = new TaskRunner(2);
console.log(task.push(exampleTaskA));
console.log(task.push(exampleTaskA));
console.log(task.push(exampleTaskA)); 
console.log(task.push(exampleTaskA));
console.log(task.push(exampleTaskA));
console.log(task.push(exampleTaskA));
console.log(task.push(exampleTaskA));
```

How can I use promises / async await to implement this? Should I wrap everything around a promise before pushing?

Can someone enlighten?

Comment: the problem appears odd, since almost nothing in JS actually runs "concurrently" unless it's an inherently async operation (e.g. AJAX)

Comment: This was asked to me in one of the interview questions in top tech companies so I'm trying to solve it using Promises @Alnitak

Comment: I believe in this case, the concurrency means that the user has to execute only "X" items from the queue at a time.

Comment: Unless it's a queue of async operations, you can't.  If you ever pass a task that's actually synchronous it'll run to the exclusion of all others.

Comment: They are .. please take a look at the task.. it's a `setTimeout` task() .. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: what you're asking is probably not suitable for this Q&A format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is setTimeout a good solution to do async functions with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626680/is-settimeout-a-good-solution-to-do-async-functions-with-javascript)

Comment: @TechnoCorner Can you change the task function to return a promise?

Comment: @MarkMeyer good plan - you can't hope to have a Promise-based scheduler if your tasks aren't already returning Promises.

Comment: Right @Alnitak -- it's just not really clear in this question what is given and what one is supposed to write. The name `exampleTaskA` suggests (at least to me) that that is an example of what the tasks look like (in which case there's not much hope).

Comment: @MarkMeyer I can actually return a promise, but how would you resolve it? `exampleTaskA` could be anything coming from another API call. I just want to throttle the execution to `this.limit` .. Appreciate your time folks.

Answer (score 6):

So if you can return a promise from your task, you can tie into the the promise's `then()` to alert you when the task is finished and when you can start another.

Here's an example similar to yours with a couple changes: we don't care about the length of the queue — you only want to know how many active jobs are present. So you can increment `active` when starting jobs a decrement it when jobs are done.

There are a lot of ways, I'm sure to do this, but here's the outline of one idea:

```js
const exampleTaskA = (name) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(`Task ${name} Done`);
  resolve()
}, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000)))

function TaskRunner(concurrency) {
  this.limit = concurrency;
  this.store = [];
  this.active = 0;
}

TaskRunner.prototype.next = function() {
  if (this.store.length) this.runTask(...this.store.shift())
}

TaskRunner.prototype.runTask = function(task, name) {
  this.active++
  console.log(`Scheduling task ${name} current active: ${this.active}`)
  task(name).then(() => {
    this.active--
    console.log(`Task ${name} returned, current active: ${this.active}`)
    this.next()
  })
}
TaskRunner.prototype.push = function(task, name) {
  if (this.active < this.limit) this.runTask(task, name)
  else {
    console.log(`queuing task ${name}`)
    this.store.push([task, name])
  }
}

var task = new TaskRunner(2);
task.push(exampleTaskA, 1)
task.push(exampleTaskA, 2)
task.push(exampleTaskA, 3)
task.push(exampleTaskA, 4)
task.push(exampleTaskA, 5)
task.push(exampleTaskA, 6)
task.push(exampleTaskA, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class TaskScheduler {
    constructor(concurrency) {
        this.limit = concurrency;
        this.active = 0;
        this.pool = [];
    }
    push(task) {
        this.pool.push(task);
        if (this.active < this.limit) {
            this.active += 1;
            this.execute(this.pool.shift());
        }
    }
    execute(task) {
        task().then(val => {
            console.log(`${val} executed`);
            this.active -= 1
            if (this.pool.length && this.active < this.limit) {
                this.execute(this.pool.shift());
            }
        });
    }
}

const task = () => new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => res('task'), 4000));
const task2 = () => new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => res('task'), 200));

const scheduler = new TaskScheduler(2);
scheduler.push(task);
scheduler.push(task2);
scheduler.push(task2);
scheduler.push(task2);
scheduler.push(task);
scheduler.push(task);
scheduler.push(task);
scheduler.push(task);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // this is without promises

```
function Task(name) {
    this.isDone = false;
    this.name = name;
}

Task.prototype.run = function() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.isDone = true;
    }, 3000);
}

function TaskScheduler(limit) {
    this.limit = limit;
    this.active = 0;
    this.pendingTasks = [];
    this.runningTasks = [];
}

TaskScheduler.prototype.runTask = function(task) {
    this.active++;
    task.run();
}

TaskScheduler.prototype.init = function() {
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
        // check and clean running tasks
        this.runningTasks = this.runningTasks.filter((task) => {
            if (task.isDone) {
                this.active--;
            }
            return !task.isDone;
        });

        while(this.pendingTasks.length) {
            if (this.active < this.limit) {
                var task = this.pendingTasks.pop();
                this.runTask(task);
                this.runningTasks.push(task);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!this.pendingTasks.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 0);
}

TaskScheduler.prototype.push = function(task) {
    this.pendingTasks.push(task);
}

var taskSecheduler = new TaskScheduler(2);
taskSecheduler.push(new Task(1));
taskSecheduler.push(new Task(2));
taskSecheduler.push(new Task(3));
taskSecheduler.push(new Task(4));
taskSecheduler.push(new Task(5));
taskSecheduler.push(new Task(6));
taskSecheduler.init();
```

});

Comment: The question explicitly asked for a solution using promises.