# Why does setTimeout function executes at last?

Tags: javascript

I have below code

```
console.log('one'); 
setTimeout(function() { console.log('two'); });
console.log('three');
```

The output of code when I run it is one, three, two

However I felt it should have been one, two, three as I haven't provided the wait time , which will set the wait time to 0 as default, i.e no waiting.

Then what is the reason that the output is one, three, two and not one, two, three.

Comment: Here is a very good response to how `setTimeout` works:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19626821/10139691

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` *schedules* the function for execution.  That scheduler doesn't do its thing until after the current thread yields control back to the browser, e.g. after the last logging statement has executed.