# Problem when executing custom typewriting function in javascript multiple times

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a game with HTML, CSS and JS which involves a typewriting animation.
I want a custom function which when called, typewrites some text. However, there is a problem when using the function multiple times. The function combines the text from the different strings which are inputted. in the function. Please help me find a solution to this. My code is similar to the W3 Schools example code with a few changes.

```js
var txt, speed, i;
function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
i++;
setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
function write(whatToWrite, howFast) {
  i = 0;
  txt = whatToWrite;
  speed = howFast;
  typeWriter();
}

//There is a problem when called multiple times
write("hello", 100);
write("world", 100);
```

```css
html{
  background-color: #0a1c08;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>The Game of Destiny</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="text"></p>
  </body>
</html>
<script src="typewriter.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the first comment said,setTimeout doesn't block, and the next write is executed immediately. To prevent this behaviour, you need to block the execution somehow. One way would be to use a callback in the timeout function, another to await a Promise. A good explanation can be found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626680/is-settimeout-a-good-solution-to-do-async-functions-with-javascript#19626821).

To solve the problem, I used a custom sleep function, which blocks the execution as long as the typing animation goes. It is not perfect and could use some more refinement, but it works.

```js
var speed;
function typeWriter(i, txt) {
 if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(() => typeWriter(i, txt), speed);
  }
}

async function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};

async function wrapper() {
  let word = "hello";
  speed = 100;
  await typeWriter(0, word);
  await sleep(word.length * speed);

  word = "world";
  speed = 200;
  await typeWriter(0, word);
}
wrapper()
```

```css
html{
  background-color: #0a1c08;
  color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>The Game of Destiny</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <p id="text"></p>
  </body>
</html>
<script src="typewriter.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` doesn't block, and the next `write` is executed immediately after the first `write` has printed the first character. Then `i` will be reset to `0`, and only the second call of `write` executes correctly.

This can be fixed by using promises, or simply by chaining the words to type in `write` function, like this:

```js
var txt = '',
  i = 0,
  pad = document.getElementById('text'),
  speed;
function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    pad.insertAdjacentText('beforeEnd', txt.charAt(i));
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

function write(whatToWrite, howFast) {
  txt += whatToWrite;
  speed = howFast;
  typeWriter();
}

write('hello', 100);
write(' world', 100);
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #0a1c08;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p id="text"></p>
```

Notice, that `txt` and `i` are now initialized at the top scope instead of `write` function. I've also defined the element to type to outside of the function, and used [`insertAdjacentText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentText) instead of `innerHTML`. These changes make the code a bit lighter to run, specifically if you're going to type very long texts to the paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for the code! It is working perfectly fine, exactly how I wanted it to. I did not know about that property of setTimeout.