# JQuery wait for $.each to finish

Tags: jquery

How can I call my sankey_continue() function after the .each is done?  I had a look at promise but don't know how to implement it or if there is a different solution.  Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

```
function pattern() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Dashboard.aspx/patterns",
                    data: '',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {

                        if (data.d != "0") {


                            //thePatterns = [];
                            var obj = $.parseJSON(data.d);

                            $.each(obj, function (i, v) {

                                svg.append('defs').append('pattern')
                                     .attr('id', v.id_pattern)
                                     .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
                                     .attr('width', eval(v.w1))
                                     .attr('height', eval(v.h1))
                                     .append("svg:image")
                                     .attr("xlink:href", v.data_pattern)
                                     .attr("width", eval(v.w1))
                                     .attr("height", eval(v.h1))
                                     .attr("x", 0)
                                     .attr("y", 0);

                            });

                            sankey_continue();
                        }
                    } //end success
                }); //end ajax call
            }
```

Comment: `$.each` isn't asynchronous, this code is fine.

Comment: what's the purpose of eval(v.w1) and stuff?

Comment: As @JamesMcLaughlin says, each is not asynchronous. Why do believe there is a problem here? I would however suggest you remove the use of `eval`.

Comment: Thanks James that gives my something else to look at for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery.each is not asynchronous even if your Ajax call is.

I suggest reading up on [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and on this [great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233633/understanding-asynchronous-code-in-laymans-terms).

Best of luck.