# How to test CRUD operations using Node.js postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, unit-testing, testing, crud

In my `create`, `read`, `update`, and `delete` functions, I am returning `true` if the transaction was successful and `false` otherwise - except for `read`, where I return the requested `data` or `null`.

This strategy should make testing easy due to simply assessing the return value given various test inputs to a test database.

My problem is that I cannot fully determine whether the transaction was successful until `db.query("...")` completes and its callback is invoked, but, by this time,the original CRUD function has returned.

**What is the common practice?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is Asynchronous, and you'll definitely want to understand how that works when using node.

There's a lot of information on the net about this, but here's a SO answer:

[Understanding Asynchronous Code in Layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233633/understanding-asynchronous-code-in-laymans-terms)

Generally, best practice in your case is to use promises.  Promises are very useful but can also take some time to learn.   I personally use the Q promise library

https://github.com/kriskowal/q

I truly hope this helps.