# javascript return value issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, reactjs-flux

i have JavaScript application in **Reactjs**. The code is as follows

```
var fnlValue;
var ReportStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
    reportMemberList: function(projectId) {
        obj.projectMember(projectId, function(repose) {
            fnlValue = repose;
        });
        return fnlValue;
    }
}
```

The `obj.projectMember` is server side calling. I need to return `fnlValue` only after getting data from server side. Here callback is used but generating bugs.

```
Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Comment: The error is looking for something *named* `callback`.  Is this used inside of `obj.projectMember`?

Comment: yes. I used inside  obj.projectMember().

Comment: Then, can you show where the error is actually occurring?

Comment: probably variable `callback` is `undefined` in this scope

Comment: can anyone can rearrange the code with callback?

Comment: You haven't posted the code that is failing. The issue is likely due to the call to `obj.projectMember`. Use the JavaScript debugger to step into the code to see what's wrong.

Comment: Even if the callback was working, you can't `return` a value from a function if that value is determined asynchronously. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233633/understanding-asynchronous-code-in-laymans-terms/11233849#11233849) for a bit more information.

Comment: It would be helpful if you said which Flux framework you are using.  I am guessing that `callback` is the callback your store should be registering with the dispatcher, which does not appear to be happening in your code.

Comment: issue fixed.All the API call is handling in action part.That is enough.