# How to store cordova geolocation result in a variable?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

Hi i have installed ngCordova and trying to accesss the lat long value using this function

```
$scope.lat = '';
$scope.long = '';

var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
                .then(function (position) {
                    $scope.lat = position.coords.latitude
                    $scope.long = position.coords.longitude

                }, function (err) {
                    // error
                });

console.log($scope.lat, $scope.long);
```

When i console it exactly below the assignment of values to lat and long variables then it provide me the result on console but when i console it outside as i have displayed in the question, it shows me empty string. What is it happening?

Comment: You are missing semicolons when assigning the values.

Comment: That is not the issue. even if i add then still it is not showing.

Comment: loop your getCurrentPosition with a timeout or use watchPosition. When you write console.log , the variables may not be yet initialized with gps data since you need some time to get these datas

Comment: welcome to async programming, your console.log is executed before the value is assigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit:** The reason why you see a correct `console.log` output when you put it inside the `.then` function is that this code is actually executed asynchronously. You can learn more about it from [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233633/understanding-asynchronous-code-in-laymans-terms).

I'll try to explain in my words: when you call the `.getCurrentPosition` function you just "leave it be", continue executing all other code, and "wait for it to finish" - and you wait for it inside the `.then` function. So, if you put `console.log` outside the `.then` function, it will actually execute before you get the actual coordinates - thus, it will print empty values, since they just may not yet exist.

Try it like this:

```js
$scope.lat = '';
$scope.long = '';

var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};

$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
        $scope.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        $scope.long = position.coords.longitude;
      
        console.log($scope.lat, $scope.long);

    },
    function (err) {
      // error
    });
```

Comment: I think you should explain why this works and his code doesn't. He has already tried that, read his last line

Comment: @jcesarmobile: ah, you're correct. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: okk got it i have to do further processing inside the .then part. thanks

Comment: Sure, no problem - I'm glad my explanation helped clear things us. Good luck with your project!