# Error with Twitter Nodejs query

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I've tried a few variations of this snippet. I keep getting the same undefined error when trying to print a json object to the console. Thanks in advance.

```
var userTweets = client.get('statuses/user_timeline', function(error, tweets, response){
if(error) throw error;
return tweets
});

console.log(userTweets)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`client.get` is asynchronous

This code is working, then you have to manage your code to wait for asynchronous response.

```
client.get('statuses/user_timeline', function(error, tweets, response){
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log(tweets)
});
```

If you have some code after client.get, you should do that

before :

```
var userTweets = client.get(..., function() {});

// do some code
console.log(userTweets);
```

after :

```
client.get(....., function(error, tweets) {
   ...
   otherCode(tweets);
});

function otherCode(userTweets) {
   // do some code
   console.log(userTweets);
}
```

I suggest you to read this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11233849/5384802 to understand asynchronous code.

Comment: Thanks, more so than logging to the console I really want the value of userTweets to be what client.get returns.