# Node Error : can't set headers after they are sent. How to solve?

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

After user click the login button, server closes itself by displaying an error that "Can't set headers after they are send." Any help?

Server.js file

```
app.put('/users/signin',function(req,res,next){
    db.collection('users',function(err,usersCollection){
        usersCollection.findOne({username:req.body.username},function(err,user){
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user.password,function(err,result){
                if(result){
                    var token = jwt.encode(user,JWT_SECRET);
                    return res.json({token:token});
                }else{
                    res.status(400).send();
                }
            })
        });   
    });
    res.send();
});
```

Controller from where i am making call to server..

```
$scope.signin = function(){
                  $http.put('/users/signin',{username:$scope.username,password:$scope.password})
         .then(function(res){
               $cookies.put('token',res.data.token);
               $scope.currentUser = $scope.username;
               alert("Successfully signed in");
           },function(err){
               alert("bad login credentials");
           });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`usersCollection.findOne` is async and its callback is called after `res.send();` as been called.

Move the `res.send();` into the `bcrypt.compare` callback.

```
app.put('/users/signin', function(req, res, next) {
    db.collection('users', function(err, usersCollection) {
        usersCollection.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function(err, result) {
                if (result) {
                    var token = jwt.encode(user, JWT_SECRET);
                    res.json({ token: token });
                } else {
                    res.status(400);
                }

                // like here
                res.send();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

## What's a callback?

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)), *a **callback** is a piece of executable code that is passed as an argument to other code*. There's nothing async by definition with a callback, but it's a really useful concept to use with async programming.

In JavaScript, a function can take a function reference as an argument which will serve as a callback.

```
function someFunction(callback) {
    console.log("before async callback");
    setTimeout(callback, 1); // calls the callback asynchronously
    console.log("after async callback");
}
```

It could be called like this, using an existing function

```
function myExistingFunction() {
    console.log("inside a callback");
}
someFunction(myExistingFunction);
```

or like this, using a function expression

```
someFunction(function(){ 
    console.log("inside a callback");
});
```

Both calls to `someFunction` would print the following to the console **in that order**:

```
before async callback
after async callback
inside a callback
```

## Why in that order?

Since `someFunction` pass the callback to the async function `setTimeout`, the callback is not called immediately, but only after the call stack finishes. So `someFunction` completely finishes, then sometime later, our callback is called.

Take a look at

- [Understanding Asynchronous Code in Layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11233849/1218980)
- [JavaScript for Beginners: Async](http://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/)
- [Node.js async in practice: When to use what?](http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice) specifically related to node and express

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for reply...I removed res.send() its working but now it's giving me another error $cookies.put is not a function.....

Comment: @ravi that's another problem, so ask another question.

Comment: @ravi best thanks on SO are upvotes and accepts, whenever you can (I know it's limited with reputation).

Comment: actually i tried to upvote and accept answer as soon as you gave me solution, but i couldn't do it due to restrictions.

Though now i have accepted solution...that i could do.
By the way, can you explain me that async function and its callback...
I mean i solved problem but couldn't understand what happened there

Comment: @ravi I'll try to add more details later to the answer.

Comment: Sure.. Looking forward to it.. Thank you very much.. :)

Comment: @ravi Sorry for the delay, I've added details about callbacks and async.

Comment: @ravi best thanks on SO are upvotes, don't hesitate to upvote answers and questions that helped you!

Comment: I really want to do it,But it's saying me you don't have enough reputation...
I can't write answers too.. so how am i supposed to increase reputation?

Comment: @ravi Totally forgot it unlocks at 15 rep. You can [ask questions and write answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts) or suggest edits which gives 2 rep when approved.