# Getting value from a callback function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback

I have a function that does a backend call and fetches an array of names. The function is like this.

```
module.exports.getTxnList = function(index, callback) {
    ....some operations
    .....
    ....
    callback(null, response);
};
```

I have one more function where i want to call this function and get this list.
Both the functions are located in the same file.

The other function is something like this.

```
module.exports.getTxnAvailability = function(index, lid, callback) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
};
```

I tried lot of things but i am not getting the data from the former function.

This is what i tried to do.

```
var that = this;
that.getTxnList(index, function(response){
    // Here you have access to your variable
    console.log("List: " + response);
})
```

And this

```
var txnList=this.getTxnList(index);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Add some of your `tries` in the question

Comment: what is the data you need?

Comment: @Shaharyar Updated the post.

Comment: @azad The response you have in getTxnList is an array. I want to get that array in the other function getTxnAvailability.

Comment: Try changing `callback(null, response)` to `callback(response)`

Comment: @PunitMittal I have to keep this order. Even if i change it to callback(response), it's not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this nodejs due to async behaviour:

```
var txnList = this.getTxnList(index);
```

Do like this:

```
//name the function for local use
var getTxnList = module.exports.getTxnList = function (index, callback) {
    ... }

module.exports.getTxnAvailability = function(index, lid, callback) {

    getTxnList(index, function(err, response){
        //here you have access to your variable
        //rest of your logic will be written here

        var txnList = response;
    }); 
};
```

[Reference: to understand how async code works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233633/understanding-asynchronous-code-in-laymans-terms)

[Reference: to understand what is callback hell and how to solve it](http://callbackhell.com/)

Comment: Not getting the data.

Comment: I guess `this` is causing the problem, I've edited to remove `this` and added a name to your function. Also you're passing `null` as your first parameter and data in second so you need to pass 2 params in your callback function.

Comment: this was needed. Otherwise it isn't able to recognize the function. But its working now. Thanks a ton for your help. You saved a lot of time :)

Comment: Callbacks are always confusing, learn to use promises when you get a chance.

Comment: Named function expressions don't create local variables.

Comment: @Bergi But they create local functions

Comment: [No they don't.](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/) The code you posted doesn't work.

Comment: @Shaharyar I am getting the data inside the getTxnList. But when i try to access the txnList variable outside this function, it shows it as null. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: @NikhilTikoo You can't access it outside the function, you'll have to write rest of your code inside the callback function. I am 2 references for you to understand async flow in the answer.

Comment: @Shaharyar Oh ok. Understood. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the informative link, I've tested it's not working. I am amazed how it worked for OP. Admitted the fact you're always right in JS :)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to call the first function in your second function like

```
module.exports.getTxnAvailability = function(index, lid, callback) {
  module.exports.getTxnList(index, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
};
```

Comment: Not getting the data