# Browser timeout occur due to heavy client side scripts

Tags: jquery

i have lots of calculation/checks to perform on client side. But my browser giving an alert of (KILL PAGES/WAIT) 4-5 times. And i have to click on wait button every time to resume it. Is there any solution to fix this

Comment: do you want to extend browser script timeout?

Comment: @Riad : yes, if its possible. Else i have to change my logic to minimize the calculation time.

Comment: Consider the answers in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598285/how-do-i-prevent-the-slow-script-warning-and-force-the-browser-to-continue-runni

Comment: Do your logic in many separate steps, and separate those steps with a little `setTimeout`

Comment: @MiikaL. : Ultimately, the solution is to change the logic to minimize the execution time. Isn't it any other way to fix this?

Comment: In the question referenced, the point was made that it would be dangerous to allow the script to decide to disable a browser safety measure. So no, you can't really go in that direction. Changing the logic to be more efficient, or then breaking it down into manageable separately run chunks is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For chrome: you can use `--disable-hang-monitor` from command line.

For firefox: change the value of `dom.max_script_run_time` key from `about:config`

for IE: change the limit from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\InternetExplorer\Styles\MaxScriptStatements`

hope this helps.