# how to detect IE11 using jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have codes $.browser to detect the browser and upon the result some layout style is based.
but now with ie 11, $.browser would give mozilla v.11. any suggestion to repair ?

Comment: I thought IE11 was up-to-date enough with modern styling that you could just use whatever styles you were using?

Comment: actually the gradient of mozilla style doesn't work. but the legacy code using $.browser just detect ie11 as mozilla. and i can't remove the $.browser.

Comment: Just so you're aware, jQuery.browser was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. They recommend you use feature detection instead. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: here's the best solution I've found:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20201867/2047385

if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(window, "ActiveXObject") && !window.ActiveXObject) {
    // is IE11
}

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

```
var isIE11 = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./);
alert(isIE11);
```

**EDIT:**

Editted in a regex fix, taken from the comments.  This fix works in the current version of IE11 as of 2/17/2014.

Comment: thanks. that's probably the only way

Comment: Fixed: `!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./);`

Comment: Or `!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./);` because it can send something along the line of `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C)`

Comment: here's the best solution I've found:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20201867/2047385

if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(window, "ActiveXObject") && !window.ActiveXObject) {
    // is IE11
}

Answer (score 5):

That last one was correct.

Example:

To apply a body style for IE only for IE7 and above (including 10+11...)

Copy/Paste this code inside the `<head></head>` tag:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
      if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) {
          $('body').addClass('if-ie');
     }


});//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: this worked best for me!