# User-agent tag for IE 11.0 compatibility

Tags: html, css, compatibility, user-agent, internet-explorer-11

I have a website which has this code in html

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)
```

and i have the following css

```
html[data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0'] #flexslider {
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -244px;
}
```

so the thing is, the above ID works fine in IE10 and doesn't work on IE 11.
What code should i put on my website to support IE 11 as well?

Comment: IE11 no longer reports as MSIE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907445/how-to-detect-ie11

Comment: Why for the love of god would you want this? Just write good code and it'll work without hacks in both IE10 and 11.

Comment: Several dups... try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871760/how-to-detect-ie-11-with-javascript-in-asp-net) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907445/how-to-detect-ie11)

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Hey Man, it's not my website and i just assigned to fix the issue, and there is also a bunch of code.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I still find CSS problems in IE10 and IE11 and there are a multitude of properties missing in both. IE still isn't that great compared to Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html[data-useragent*='rv:11.0'] #flexslider {
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -244px;
}
```