# Is that possible redirect to open in Chrome from IE, but also have that redirect work if Chrome is already in use?

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, internet-explorer-11

I made a redirect link for my website from IE11 to Chrome by using ActiveXObject it works when I open the link in IE but when I open that redirect link in Chrome It doesn't work and is there a way to fix that problem.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Redirect</title>
<h1>Browser Redirect</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
  {
   varshell= new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
   shell.run("Chrome http://example.com");
  }
  setTimeout("pageRedirect()",3000);
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Chrome does not, and never will, support ActiveXObject. This example will also only work in very limited IE11 cases and usually requires security setting modifications. (There are some Chrome add-ons that do, or did, by embedding IE in tabs; this is outside the scope of the question.)

Comment: "Normal" redirects, within the current browser, can be done merely by assigning to `window.location` - https://stackoverflow.com/q/503093/2864740 (there are a few variants, and some less-common alternatives)

Comment: Do you also want to redirect to another site in Chrome? If so, I think Stephen Ostermiller's answer is right. It will open Chrome and redirect to the site if you open the page in IE and directly redirect if you open the page in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your `pageRedirect` function [check if active X is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313438/how-do-i-detect-if-activex-is-enabled-in-the-browser-of-client) and choose how to redirect based on that:

```js
function pageRedirect(){
  var url="http://example.com"
  if ("ActiveXObject" in window) new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").run("Chrome "+url);
  else location.href = url
}
setTimeout(pageRedirect,3000);
```

I've also changed a few other things:

- You don't define the `pageRedirect` in your example code, so it doesn't look like your code would actually work.
- `setTimeout` can take a function name as the first argument and run that function.  It is usually preferable to do that than to pass it a string of code to execute.
- You don't need to define the `varshell` variable, you can just call `run` directly on the `new` object that is constructed without assigning it to a variable.

Comment: The standard redirect approach also works in IE11 (and before). Presumably the use of ActiveX is to “open chrome”. However ActiveX probably shouldn’t be used at all here and it will fail on public sites, even in IE (or when the WScript.run call otherwise fails). If IE really isn’t to be used, a banner (or other warning) is more generally suitable (fsvo) so the user can switch to a “modern” browser manually.